# How to extract data from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a JavaScript object and I need to retrieve `free_time`, `done_ratio`, `criticalTask`, `dependency` for each **task** element.

This is what i have done, but it doesn't work.

```js
var mock_data_allocation = {"allocation":[{"id":7,"name":"Manoj D","limit":4.0,"available_time":16.0,"tasks":[{"id":34,"name":"issue_25","projectId":3,"startDate":"2015-12-28","dueDate":"2015-12-31","done_ratio":0,"estimate":3,"remaining":0,"sprintId":"2015-12-28_2015-12-31","criticalTask":true,"assigned":true,"tracker":"Bug","status":"New","assignedTo":"Manoj D","dependency":[]},{"id":36,"name":"issue_27","projectId":3,"startDate":"2015-12-28","dueDate":"2015-12-31","done_ratio":0,"estimate":3,"remaining":0,"sprintId":"2015-12-28_2015-12-31","criticalTask":true,"assigned":true,"tracker":"Bug","status":"New","assignedTo":"Manoj D","dependency":[33,34]},{"id":38,"name":"issue_29","projectId":3,"startDate":"2015-12-28","dueDate":"2015-12-31","done_ratio":0,"estimate":5,"remaining":0,"sprintId":"2015-12-28_2015-12-31","criticalTask":true,"assigned":true,"tracker":"Bug","status":"New","assignedTo":"Manoj D","dependency":[35,36]},{"id":39,"name":"issue_30","projectId":3,"startDate":"2015-12-28","dueDate":"2015-12-31","done_ratio":0,"estimate":4,"remaining":0,"sprintId":"2015-12-28_2015-12-31","criticalTask":true,"assigned":true,"tracker":"Bug","status":"New","assignedTo":"Manoj D","dependency":[37,38]}]},{"id":5,"name":"Thisun H","limit":4.0,"available_time":16.0,"tasks":[{"id":33,"name":"issue_24","projectId":3,"startDate":"2015-12-28","dueDate":"2015-12-31","done_ratio":0,"estimate":5,"remaining":0,"sprintId":"2015-12-28_2015-12-31","criticalTask":false,"assigned":true,"tracker":"Bug","status":"New","assignedTo":"Thisun H","dependency":[]},{"id":35,"name":"issue_26","projectId":3,"startDate":"2015-12-28","dueDate":"2015-12-31","done_ratio":0,"estimate":2,"remaining":0,"sprintId":"2015-12-28_2015-12-31","criticalTask":false,"assigned":true,"tracker":"Bug","status":"New","assignedTo":"Thisun H","dependency":[]},{"id":37,"name":"issue_28","projectId":3,"startDate":"2015-12-28","dueDate":"2015-12-31","done_ratio":0,"estimate":6,"remaining":0,"sprintId":"2015-12-28_2015-12-31","criticalTask":false,"assigned":true,"tracker":"Bug","status":"New","assignedTo":"Thisun H","dependency":[34]}]}]};



    $(mock_data_allocation.allocation).each( function(i, value){
        $('.taskdetail').append('<tr>' +
                                '<td>'+ (i+1) +'</td>'+ 
                                '<td>'+ value.tasks.name +'</td>'+ 
                                '<td>'+value.tasks.free_time+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+value.tasks.done_ratio+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+value.tasks.criticalTask+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+value.tasks.dependency.length+'</td>'+
                                
                            '</tr>');
        });
```

```html
<tbody class="taskdetail"></tbody>
```

Currently the output is:

```
1   undefined   undefined   0   true    0
2   undefined   undefined   0   false   0
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". Is the output wrong? Are you getting errors?

Comment: This is the output, in a table format...
`1 undefined undefined 0 true 0
2 undefined undefined 0 false 0`

Comment: `value.tasks` is not an object but an array, so you need to iterate over it too

Comment: This is not a JSON object. It's a JavaScript object. JSON is a character-based data interchange format. You're not trying to parse it. You're trying to extract data from it. Parse means to analyze a string representation of a program in accordance with a grammar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tasks` property of the `value` objects is an *array of objects* but your code assumes that it's an *object*. Your code fails as the `tasks` array doesn't have `dependency` property and subsequently `value.tasks.dependency.length` fails as `value.tasks.dependency` returns `undefined` and `undefined` doesn't have `length` property.

You should either get a specific  element from the `tasks` array:

```
.append('<tr>' +
    '<td>'+ (i+1) +'</td>'+ 
    '<td>'+ value.tasks[0].name +'</td>'+ 
    '<td>'+value.tasks[0].free_time+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+value.tasks[0].done_ratio+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+value.tasks[0].criticalTask+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+value.tasks[0].dependency.length+'</td>'+ 
'</tr>');
```

or iterate through it:

```
var $target = $('.taskdetail');
$.each(mock_data_allocation.allocation, function(i, value) {
    $.each(value.tasks, function(ii, task) {
              $target.append('<tr>' +
                                '<td>'+ (ii+1) +'</td>'+ 
                                '<td>'+ task.name +'</td>'+ 
                                '<td>'+task.free_time+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+task.done_ratio+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+task.criticalTask+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+task.dependency.length+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>');
    });
});
```

Also you should not create a jQuery object by passing a regular object to jQuery. Use the [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) utility function instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this....

```
  $.each(mock_data_allocation.allocation,function(i, value){
    $.each(value.tasks,function(j,val){
        $('.taskdetail').append('<tr>' +
                            '<td>'+ (j+1) +'</td>'+ 
                            '<td>'+ val.name +'</td>'+ 
                            '<td>'+val.free_time+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+val.done_ratio+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+val.criticalTask+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+val.dependency.length+'</td>'+

                        '</tr>');
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(mock_data_allocation.allocation)` is nothing, in fact `$(mock_data_allocation)` is nothing.

You may want `jQuery.each( mock_data_allocation.allocation, function ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here point a main issue, which is the way the object is explored,and I agree.
But I don't understand why there is no answer pointing another issue: **the needed result comes from two different levels in the original object**.

At the `task` level are the informations `name`, `done_ratio`, and `criticalTask`.
But it's one level up that resides `free_time` (in fact named `available_time`), which is the same for all tasks (note #2 in the code below).
The same applies for the 1st `<td>`, which includes a counter: this one might be computed either globally or at the tasks level (note #1 in the code below).

Here is a really working solution ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cFreed/8z3ndzjb/1/)):

```
var all = mock_data_allocation.allocation;
for (var i = 0, n = all.length; i < n; i++) {
  var availTime = all[i].available_time,
      tasks = all[i].tasks;
  for (var j = 0, m = tasks.length; j < m; j++) {
    var task = tasks[j];
    $('.taskdetail').append(
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + (i + 1) + '-' + (j + 1) +'</td>'+ // <-- #1
      '<td>' + task.name + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + availTime + '</td>' + // <-- #2
      '<td>' + task.done_ratio + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + task.criticalTask + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + task.dependency.length + '</td>'+
      '</tr>'
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you must unpack the tasks array

```
var mock_data_allocation = {
  "allocation": [{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Manoj D",
    "limit": 4.0,
    "available_time": 16.0,
    "tasks": [{
      "id": 34,
      "name": "issue_25",
      "projectId": 3,
      "startDate": "2015-12-28",
      "dueDate": "2015-12-31",
      "done_ratio": 0,
      "estimate": 3,
      "remaining": 0,
      "sprintId": "2015-12-28_2015-12-31",
      "criticalTask": true,
      "assigned": true,
      "tracker": "Bug",
      "status": "New",
      "assignedTo": "Manoj D",
      "dependency": []
    }, {
      "id": 36,
      "name": "issue_27",
      "projectId": 3,
      "startDate": "2015-12-28",
      "dueDate": "2015-12-31",
      "done_ratio": 0,
      "estimate": 3,
      "remaining": 0,
      "sprintId": "2015-12-28_2015-12-31",
      "criticalTask": true,
      "assigned": true,
      "tracker": "Bug",
      "status": "New",
      "assignedTo": "Manoj D",
      "dependency": [33, 34]
    }, {
      "id": 38,
      "name": "issue_29",
      "projectId": 3,
      "startDate": "2015-12-28",
      "dueDate": "2015-12-31",
      "done_ratio": 0,
      "estimate": 5,
      "remaining": 0,
      "sprintId": "2015-12-28_2015-12-31",
      "criticalTask": true,
      "assigned": true,
      "tracker": "Bug",
      "status": "New",
      "assignedTo": "Manoj D",
      "dependency": [35, 36]
    }, {
      "id": 39,
      "name": "issue_30",
      "projectId": 3,
      "startDate": "2015-12-28",
      "dueDate": "2015-12-31",
      "done_ratio": 0,
      "estimate": 4,
      "remaining": 0,
      "sprintId": "2015-12-28_2015-12-31",
      "criticalTask": true,
      "assigned": true,
      "tracker": "Bug",
      "status": "New",
      "assignedTo": "Manoj D",
      "dependency": [37, 38]
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Thisun H",
    "limit": 4.0,
    "available_time": 16.0,
    "tasks": [{
      "id": 33,
      "name": "issue_24",
      "projectId": 3,
      "startDate": "2015-12-28",
      "dueDate": "2015-12-31",
      "done_ratio": 0,
      "estimate": 5,
      "remaining": 0,
      "sprintId": "2015-12-28_2015-12-31",
      "criticalTask": false,
      "assigned": true,
      "tracker": "Bug",
      "status": "New",
      "assignedTo": "Thisun H",
      "dependency": []
    }, {
      "id": 35,
      "name": "issue_26",
      "projectId": 3,
      "startDate": "2015-12-28",
      "dueDate": "2015-12-31",
      "done_ratio": 0,
      "estimate": 2,
      "remaining": 0,
      "sprintId": "2015-12-28_2015-12-31",
      "criticalTask": false,
      "assigned": true,
      "tracker": "Bug",
      "status": "New",
      "assignedTo": "Thisun H",
      "dependency": []
    }, {
      "id": 37,
      "name": "issue_28",
      "projectId": 3,
      "startDate": "2015-12-28",
      "dueDate": "2015-12-31",
      "done_ratio": 0,
      "estimate": 6,
      "remaining": 0,
      "sprintId": "2015-12-28_2015-12-31",
      "criticalTask": false,
      "assigned": true,
      "tracker": "Bug",
      "status": "New",
      "assignedTo": "Thisun H",
      "dependency": [34]
    }]
  }]
};



$(mock_data_allocation.allocation).each(function(i, value) {
  $(value.tasks).each(function(index, el) {
    $('.taskdetail').append('<tr>' +
      '<td>' + (i + 1) + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + el.name + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + el.free_time + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + el.done_ratio + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + el.criticalTask + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + el.dependency.length + '</td>' +

      '</tr>');
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This has no sense, and doesn't answer the question!

Answer (score -2):

Your problem lies in the use of `$(mock_data_allocation.allocation).each` There are two different .each functions in JQuery

`$(selector).each()` - Used to Iterate over a jQuery object

and

`jQuery.each()` - A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays.

`mock_data_allocation` is not a DOM element and so trying to make it into a JQuery object with `$(mock_data_allocation.allocation)` fails because `mock_data_allocation.allocation` is not a DOM element.

You need to iterate over a data object so instead of

```
$(mock_data_allocation.allocation).each( function(i, value){...
```

you should be doing

```
$.each(mock_data_allocation.allocation, function(i, value){...
```

That will cure the 'undefined' problem.

Comment: jQuery is capably of handling arrays this way.

Comment: -1 This is not the problem encountered by the OP and doesn't answer the question in any way - this is just an alternative syntax on a point of detail - you obviously didn't try to run the OP's code

Comment: Yes it is. But there is no point in turning `mock_data_allocation.allocation` into a JQuery object as @mars is doing

Comment: @Jivan It is exactly the reason for all the undefined values. There is a huge difference between the functions $(selector).each() and JQuery. each() they are NOT the same function.